# jsoup escaping ampersand in link href

Tags: jsoup

JSoup is escaping the ampersand in the query portion of a URL in a link href.  Given the sample below

```
    String l_input = "<html><body>before <a href=\"http://a.b.com/ct.html\">link text</a> after</body></html>";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document l_doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(l_input);
    org.jsoup.select.Elements l_html_links = l_doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element l : l_html_links) {
      l.attr("href", "http://a.b.com/ct.html?a=111&b=222");
    }
    String l_output = l_doc.outerHtml();
```

The output is

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    before 
    <a href="http://a.b.com/ct.html?a=111&amp;b=222">link text</a> after
    </body>
    </html>
```

The single & is being escaped to &amp; .  Shouldn't it stay as & ?

Comment: `&` fails in the XHTML documents as not a valid symbol or valid XML. So, it should be parsed to standardize in  all the Markups

Comment: SRy - not sure I completely understand.  Are you saying that the lone ampersand in the URL is invalid, and that it should be the escaped/entity version instead?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you can't do it. I went through the source and found the place where the escape happens.

It is defined in the [Attribute.java](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Attribute.java#L68)

```
/**
 Get the HTML representation of this attribute; e.g. {@code href="index.html"}.
 @return HTML
 */
public String html() {
    return key + "=\"" + Entities.escape(value, (new Document("")).outputSettings()) + "\"";
}
```

There you see it is using the [Entities.java](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.java#L22) jsoup takes the default outputSettings of `new document("");` That's way you can't override this settings.

Maybe you should post a feature request for that.

Btw: The default Escape mode is set to `base`.

The [Documet.java](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.java#L18) creates a default `OutputSettings` Objects, and [there](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.java#L210) it is defined. See:

```
/**
 * A HTML Document.
 *
 * @author Jonathan Hedley, jonathan@hedley.net 
 */
public class Document extends Element {
    private OutputSettings outputSettings = new OutputSettings();
    // ...
}


/**
 * A Document's output settings control the form of the text() and html() methods.
 */
public static class OutputSettings implements Cloneable {
    private Entities.EscapeMode escapeMode = Entities.EscapeMode.base;
    // ...
}
```

**Workaround (unescape as XML):**

With the `StringEscapeUtils` from the [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) project you can escape those thinks easly. See:

```
    String unescapedXml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(l_output);
    System.out.println(unescapedXml);
```

This will print:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  before 
  <a href="http://a.b.com/ct.html?a=111&b=222">link text</a> after
 </body>
</html>
```

But of course, it will replace all `&amp;`...

Answer (score 1):

What Jsoup does it's actually the right way to write urls. E.g. if you write "id=1&copy=true" browser may interpret it as "id=1©=true". So you have to scape it.

I got this from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsoup/eK4XxHc4Tro

Comment: That is incorrect.  The only way that the browser would interpret &copy as the copyright symbol is if it ends with a semi-colon: `&copy;=` will produce the copyright symbol, but `&copy=` will not.