# Is there a way extract raw attribute value using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

In Jsoup,`Element.attr` returns the parsed value of an attribute.

For example if the attribute's value is `foo &amp; bar`, `Element.attr` returns `foo & bar`.

Is there a way to return the raw value of an attribute using Jsoup?

At the moment I am using `Element.toString` and extract the attribute value manually, but I am looking for a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259690/jsoup-escaping-ampersand-in-link-href